# using make command infix to postfix conversion

Tags: linux

this is my 1.c content

```
#include "2.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void push(int ele)
{
    stack[tos]=ele;
    tos++;
}

char pop()
{
    tos--;
    return(stack[tos]);
}

void show()
{
    int x=tos;    
    printf("--The Stack elements are.....");
    while(x!=0)
        printf("%c, ",stack[--x]);
}

//Function to get the precedence of an operator
int prec(char symbol)
{
    if(symbol== '(')
        return 0;

    if(symbol== ')')
        return 0;

    if(symbol=='+' || symbol=='-')
        return 1;

    if(symbol=='*' || symbol=='/')
        return 2;

    if(symbol=='^')
        return 3;

    return 0;
}
```

and this is my 2.h content

```
#define size 10

char stack[size];
int tos=0,ele;

void push();

char pop();

void show();

int isempty();

int isfull();

char infix[30], output[30];

int prec(char);
```

and my main.c content is

```
#include "2.h"
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,length;

    char temp;

    printf("\nEnter an infix expression:");

    scanf("%s",infix);

    printf("\nThe infix expresson is %s",infix);

    length=strlen(infix);

    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        //Numbers are added to the out put QUE

        if(infix[i]!='+' && infix[i]!='-' && infix[i]!='*' && infix[i]!='/' && 
                infix[i]!='^' && infix[i]!=')' && infix[i]!='(' )
        {
            output[j++]=infix[i];

            printf("\nThe element added to Q is:%c",infix[i]);

        }
        //If an operator or a bracket is encountered...
        else
        {
            if(tos==0) //If there are no elements in the stack, the operator is added to it
            {
                push(infix[i]);

                printf("\nThe pushed element is:%c",infix[i]);

            }
            else
            {
                //Operators or pushed or poped based on the order of precedence
                if(infix[i]!=')' && infix[i]!='(')
                {
                    if(prec(infix[i]) <= prec(stack[tos-1]))
                    {
                        temp=pop();

                        printf("\n the poped element is :%c",temp);

                        output[j++]=temp;
                        push(infix[i]);
                        printf("\n The pushed element is :%c",infix[i]);

                        show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        push(infix[i]);
                        printf("\nThe pushed element is:%c",infix[i]);

                        show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(infix[i]=='(')
                    {
                        push(infix[i]);

                        printf("\nThe pushed-- element is:%c",infix[i]);
                    }

                    if(infix[i]==')')
                    {
                        temp=pop();

                        while(temp!='(')
                        {
                            output[j++]=temp;

                            printf("\nThe element added to Q is:%c",temp);

                            //temp=pop();
                            printf("\n the poped element is :%c",temp);
                            temp=pop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\nthe infix expression is: %s",output);
    }

    while(tos!=0)
    {
        output[j++]=pop();
    }

    printf("the infix expression is: %s\n",output);
}
```

i am doing this using MAKE in linux

the code is

```
myapp: main.o 1.o
    gcc -o myapp main.c 1.c

main.o: main.c 2.h
    gcc -c main.c

1.o: 1.c 2.h
    gcc -c 1.c
```

but iin coming the error coming

```
gcc -o myapp main.c 1.c
/tmp/ccy0qyI1.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `tos'
/tmp/ccQZzbOI.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [myapp] Error 1
```

i m trying to fix it up. but not able to resolve

Comment: looks like a homework problem, please tag it as so.

Comment: Please, format your question so that code is readable. I tried but gave up at `main()`. You can use the 101/010 button to insert code.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a global variable `tos` in a header file, which you include both from `1.c` and `main.c`. So you end up with two global variables with the same name. The linker does not like that. As a traditional-unix extension, the linker may cope with such a situation if the multiply-defined variable is not explicitly initialized, but your code initializes the variable.

I recommend reading the [K&R book](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/) which you will find in any decent university library.

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas gave you a good explanation of your problem. The global variable `tos` declaration is in the header file `2.h` which is included twice via `#include` in `1.c` and `main.c`.

If you want to *share* the variable `tos` you should declaration it in 1.c or main.c, and modify 2.h to declare it as an `extern`, e.g.:

1.c:

```
int tos = 0;
```

2.h:

```
extern int tos;
```

Then you can access tos from main.c, but the variable is only defined once.

*Sidebar:* Just a suggestion for your own benefit, and for the benefit of sharing future questions in StackOverflow, try to minimize the source code, to the bare necessaries of generating the error. To the point where the program is trivial, because then the bug will be easier to isolate (for you and everyone else), and clearer for the reader, what they should focus on. As well, @Thomas suggestion of *The C Programming Language* is strongly encouraged as an excellent recommendation for **any** C programmer.